# Sequential number generator with a twist

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript

I have an assets list.  The asset needs to have an asset number assigned upon creation.  The format of the number should be A-99999.  There are existing asset numbers I have to work around in order to generate the new number.

For instance, an asset is added to the list. The available numbers are 00250 - 00304, inclusive.  Another group of available numbers is 00308 - 00404.  I have to generate a sequential number > 249, < 404 being careful not to generate a number that's already been created (like 00307).

How can I generate the numbers in a SPD workflow?